# Execve inline assembly

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, system-calls, inline-assembly

I recently got into gcc's inline assembly and having basic assembly knowledge, I understood how to make syscalls pretty well until I tried to do a simple sys_execve with one or more arguments.
The system call execve works fine if I am not passing it any additional parameters, and just runs the executable without parameters when trying to pass any.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *argv[]={"/bin/echo","parameter test", NULL};

int main(){
  __asm__ volatile ("int $0x80"
          :
          :"a"(11), // syscall number (execve)
           "b"(argv[0]), // filename
           "c"(argv), // arguments
           "d"(0)); // env
  return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what could go wrong, as I have tested this with

```
execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
```

and it worked as expected.

Comment: Looking at the api for [sys_execve](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html), I'm not sure you've got the parameters correct.  Also, are you compiling for x64?  If so, you aren't supposed to use int 0x80.

Comment: I am compiling for x64, and with my current progress, the filename part is correct, since any executable I try to execute works. The part I'm stuck on is giving it any parameters. I user [this](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) to determine what I had to pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is 32 bit code, using 32 bit conventions. Compile using `gcc -m32` and it will work. Alternatively, switch to the proper 64 bit version such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *argv[]={"/bin/echo","parameter test", NULL};

int main(){
    int ret;
  __asm__ volatile ("syscall"
          :"=a" (ret)
          :"a"(59), // syscall number (execve)
           "D"(argv[0]), // filename
           "S"(argv), // arguments
           "d"(0) // env
          :"rcx","r11","cc");
  return 0;
}
```

The actual problem is that you have 64 bit pointers in the array, but the 32 bit compatibility interrupt that you use of course expects 32 bit poiters.

Comment: The `=a` is worth explicitly pointing out: the system call returns a value in the `eax` (or `rax`) register, so the compiler needs to know that this is happening.  Otherwise it will assume that the asm code leaves `eax` unmodified, and if it needs the value 59 later in the code, it might try to load it from `eax`.  That will cause problems because in fact `eax` has been overwritten with the return value of the system call.  Probably unlikely to actually cause a problem in this code, but important to pay attention to in general.

Comment: By the way, from what I read in the amd64 abi, a system call may clobber `r11` as well as `rcx`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's correct, the design of `syscall` / `sysret` guarantees that a `syscall` will always clobber rcx and r11 (with RIP and RFLAGS).  Having the kernel even see what was in those regs would require user-space cooperation (e.g. putting them on the stack).  Linux syscalls don't look at the user-space stack, so the ABI just keeps it simple and has system calls clobber those two regs on amd64, unlike 32bit `int 0x80` where only `eax` is modified (return value).

Comment: Also, I'd suggest `return 1` from `main`, since that will only be reached if `execve` returns an error instead of working.  And give the global `argv` a different name, and make it `const` so it can be in the `.rodata` section, in case the compiler doesn't manage to do that on its own.

Comment: @NateEldredge In addition to clobbering rcx and r11, it clobbers flags.  Shouldn't you also add "cc"?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I could have sworn I have read somewhere that clobbering `cc` is optional because it's automatically assumed. But I can't find that now and in any case adding it is the safe way.

Comment: @jester Strictly speaking, you are correct that "cc" is always implied for extended asm on x86.  It currently serves as nothing more than a comment.  Still, the comment is appropriate in this context.  FWIW, I'm currently trying to get this fact added to the gcc docs.